# macOS draw a rectangle with two holes inside

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, mask, cgrect

I have one big CGRect and two small CGRect inside. I want to draw the big CGRect in red and to form two transparent holes corresponding to the small CGRect.

I am not able to do it. I have tried to use NSBezierPath but in macOS there is no method NSBezierPath.CGPath like in UIBezierPath for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use Core Graphics. You can create a `NSView` subclass and just `stroke`/`fill` the path in `draw(_:)`. In Swift 3:

```
class HolyView: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        let path = ... // build the `NSBezierPath` however you want

        NSColor.blue.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }

}
```

You can then add that view programmatically, or you can make it `@IBDesignable` and add it directly on your storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Two things: 
1) how can path "know" where to be drawn, I mean I expected to pass it the reference of a `cgContext` or something else. 
2) now I try implementing this solution, is it possible to work with layers too?

Comment: You just add it to your view hierarchy. Do you just want to show the view, or is there some reason why you need to use CoreGraphics' `cgContext`?

Comment: The even/odd rule winding rule would fill the intersection with the fill color. If you don't want it to do that, you'd have to define a path for the intersecting circles (e.g. not two full circles, but two partial arcs whose start and end angles are chosen carefully to stop where the other picks up; some basic trigonometry is needed, but it's not hard).

Comment: Thank you. I realised that this answers, that solves my question, does not fit for my original problem. So I will be more detailed in another answer. For the moment I mark this as the best question!

Comment: Here the question @Rob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202823/filter-on-calayer-except-for-a-shape-which-is-an-union-of-non-necessarily-disti

Comment: In your comment, you ask whether you can use layers. Sure, use `CAShapeLayer`, but I'd build a `CGMutablePath` directly rather than building a `NSBezierPath` and then creating a `CGMutablePath` from that.

Comment: One more thing: I think that in order to create the "holes" the line `path.move(to: .zero)` in your question before the edit is a key point. Can you explain better how to tell Xcode that we want to get an hole instead that to add a figure?

Comment: No, that `move(to: .zero)` is not needed. I just like to move to the point in case you're drawing the path. See https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/b7a180aac09dcfc3b07c202cd89d786f. But you're not stroking the path, presumably, just filling it, so it's academic. That's why I deleted the path related code, as it wasn't relevant to the broader question and it seemed like we could get lost in irrelevant stuff like this.